# "Unknown visitor type" in npm package, protagonist

Tags: node.js, postman, apiblueprint, drafter

I am trying to convert my API Blueprints to a Postman collection through `protagonist` (and then through `blueman`), but when I use protagonist, I am getting the following result, no matter what I do.

```
{
  "element": "parseResult",
  "content": [
    {
      "element": "annotation",
      "meta": {
        "classes": [
          "warning"
        ]
      },
      "attributes": {
        "code": 4,
        "sourceMap": [
          {
            "element": "sourceMap",
            "content": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "content": "Unknown visitor type"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have eliminated the possibility that it is from my code, as I get this result when I simply use the example code of:

```
var result = protagonist.parseSync('# My API');
```

I have tried `protagonist` 1.2.6 and 1.3.0-pre.0, and I get the same result. It seems to be coming from [here](https://github.com/apiaryio/drafter/blob/master/src/refract/VisitableBy.h#L42), but I don't understand what is causing it.

### System Information

- **OS X** - 10.11.4
- **Node** - 4.4.0

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in protagonist, it has been resolved with the version `1.3.0-pre.1` see the [github issue](https://github.com/apiaryio/protagonist/issues/136) for the details.